# Open net core web api in Swagger and console

Tags: c#, .net

How can i open an Web api project on swagger and console also ? I want to implement a logger and make request from swagger. Currenly it opens only the swagger OR console.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you share some more information, like how are you running the web api project and how are you accessing the swagger interface?

Comment: I have an MVC app and Api running on different project and when I run it, both open on separate windows on Browser, but the Console did not open on the API project as it should. @DurgaPrasad

Comment: If you are running the application from ide like visual studio then try changing the hosting server from iis express to Kestrel server which will launch your api project in a console window